# {$taxonomy}_row_actions for all custom taxonomies

Tags: row-actions

I want to add a row action to ALL custom taxonomies.  This is for use in a plugin so I want this to apply to whatever taxonomies exist rather than adding a filter for each taxonomy manually like below.  I can't figure out a simple way to do this.

```
    add_filter( 'category_row_actions', 'category_row_actions', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`tag_row_actions` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/tag_row_actions/) (which was deprecated in WP v3.0.0, but then restored in WP v5.4.2) to target ***any taxonomies*** (Tags/`post_tag`, Categories/`category`, `a_custom_taxonomy`, etc.), so just replace the `category_row_actions` with `tag_row_actions`:

```php
add_filter( 'tag_row_actions', 'category_row_actions', 10, 2 );
```

Or you could use [`get_taxonomies()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_taxonomies/) with an early hook like `admin_init` (that runs after `init`), and then add your filter for the target taxonomies like so:

```php
add_action( 'admin_init', function () {
    // This adds the filter for *all* taxonomies.
    foreach ( get_taxonomies() as $taxonomy ) {
        add_filter( "{$taxonomy}_row_actions", 'category_row_actions', 10, 2 );
    }

/*
    // This one adds the filter for *public* taxonomies only.
    foreach ( get_taxonomies( array( 'public' => true ) ) as $taxonomy ) {
        add_filter( "{$taxonomy}_row_actions", 'category_row_actions', 10, 2 );
    }
*/
} );
```

Comment: Awesome!  Just what I was looking for.  Thanks